# Catch Javascript CustomEvent by jQuery on() preserving custom properties at first "level"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a setup theoretically like this [see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/GeZyw/**] :

```js
var EventTest = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.element.addEventListener('click', elementClick);
    
    function elementClick() {
        var event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
        event.initEvent('myevent', false, false);
        event['xyz']='abc';
        event.customData='test';
        console.log(event);
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

var element = document.getElementById('test');
var test = new EventTest(element);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#test").on('myevent', function(e) {
        console.log('myevent', e);
    });
});
```

What I want is to create a CustomEvent in pure Javascript, enrich it with some properties and trigger that event so it can be cached also by a library like jQuery.

As you can see in the fiddle, the CustomEvent is triggered well and it is actually populated with custom properties - but when it reaches jQuery `on()` the custom properties is gone from the first level. My custom properties is now demoted to `e.originalEvent.xyz` and so on.

That is not very satisfactory. I want at least my own properties to be at the first level.

**Also**, in a perfect world, I would like to get rid of most of the standard properties in the dispatched event, so it contained (theoretically optimal) :

```js
e = {
  xyz : 'abc',
  customData : 'test'
}
```

Is that possible at all? If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into the same issue, couple of months ago, the point is:

> When an event is received by jQuery, it normalizes the event properties before it dispatches the event to registered event handlers.

and also:

> Event handlers won't be receiving the original event. Instead they are getting a new [jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object with properties copied from the raw HTML event.

Why jQuery does that:

> because it can't set properties on a raw HTML event.

I had decided to do the same, I started to do it with a nasty way, and my code ended up so messy, at the end I decided to use jQuery.trigger solution, and pass my event object as the second param, like:

```
$("#test").bind("myevent", function(e, myeventobj) { 
    alert(myeventobj.xyz);
});
var myobj = {"xyz":"abc"};
$("#test").trigger("myevent", myobj);
```

for more info check this link out: **[.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)**

Comment: +1. I have this in my mind myself. But what I want is to avoid **any** use of jQuery from my code, so `trigger` is really not an option. What I want is to make it "easier" **if** you later on are catching the event(s) by jQuery.

Comment: I give you the accepted answer. Now realizing it was a llame question. I have been through the jQuery code and there is nothing I can do. And all in all it doesnt matter, I just wanted "clean" eventData, a kind of hybris, but what the heck. I do not use the `trigger`-method as you suggested because I attend to avoid jQuery, but you explained something I didnt knew before.