# CustomEvent add property in dispatch and to be received in jquery listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to pass additional properties to the new event in native javascript without using the `detail` and can be received by jquery? Like this example. I would like the event to directly have the `namespace` property instead of passing inside the detail `detail: {namespace = ''}`. This will work with native js and native listeners.

```js
var event = new CustomEvent('myEvent', {bubbles: true})
event.namespace = "";

var el = document.querySelector('span');

el.addEventListener("myEvent", function(e){
  console.log("namespace is defined?", e.namespace !== undefined);
});

el.dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<span></span>
```

The reason is some libraries I use uses jquery and it explicitly looks for the `namespace` prop. This will work also with jquery and its listeners.

```js
var el = $('span');

el.on("myEvent", function(e){
  console.log("namespace is defined?", e.namespace !== undefined);
});

el.trigger('myEvent');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><span>
```

However, this will not work with native js but jquery listeners. The reason is listeners are written in the library with jquery, but I don't want to use jquery in my code to write the events.

```js
var event = new CustomEvent('myEvent', {bubbles: true})
event.namespace = "";

var el = document.querySelector('span');

$(el).on("myEvent", function(e){
  // I have no control inside here
  console.log("namespace is defined?", e.namespace !== undefined);
});

el.dispatchEvent(event)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Is there a way to solve this or I have to use jquery?

Comment: Seems related ~ [Catch Javascript CustomEvent by jQuery on() preserving custom properties at first “level”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835724/catch-javascript-customevent-by-jquery-on-preserving-custom-properties-at-firs)

Comment: Yes, so the question here is that is there a way to avoid jquery methods like `trigger` at all?